# How do I get latest versions of modules in my left inner join?

Tags: sql-server, left-join, inner-join, ssms, dotnetnuke

I am using a SQL left inner join to query 4 tables. One of the tables `HtmlText` contains both `ModuleID` and `Version` columns. What I want to accomplish is pull only the MAX version of every `ModuleID` from a specific site or `PortalID`. Here is what I have tried

```
SELECT TBS.PortalID [PortalID], TBS.TabID [TabID], TBS.TabName [TabName], 
TBS.TabPath [TabPath], HTM.Version[Version], TBM.ModuleID [ModuleID],     
MDS.ModuleID[ModuleID], HTM.Content[Content]
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Tabs] TBS
Inner JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[Modules] MDS 
LEFT JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[TabModules] TBM
LEFT JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[HtmlText] HTM 
ON HTM.[ModuleID] = TBM.[ModuleID]
ON MDS.[ModuleID] = TBM.[ModuleID]
ON TBS.[TabID] = TBM.[TabID] 
WHERE TBS.[PortalID] = '0' AND DataLength(HTM.[Content]) <> 0  
AND Version = (Select MAX([Version]) from [MyDB].[dbo].[HtmlText])
```

But this only gives me the `ModuleID` with the largest `Version`, instead of the MAX Version of all of the different `ModuleID`s

[image]

Comment: Move your `AND Version = ...` to your `ON` condition.  It's transforming the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` by including it in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Siyual I tried your suggestion and I got the same result

Comment: try changing your last predicate to this: (Select MAX([Version]) from [MyDB].[dbo].[HtmlText] where ModuleId = HTM.ModuleId).  This will get the max version for that particular module

Comment: @SteveR I used your suggestion as the solution please make this into an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your last predicate to this:

```
AND Version = (Select MAX([Version]) from [MyDB].[dbo].[HtmlText] where ModuleId = HTM.ModuleId)
```

This will get the max version for that particular module

Answer (score 2):

Use the ROW_NUMBER() windowing function in a derived table (subquery in the FROM clause):

```
(SELECT iHTM.ModuleID,
       iHTM.Version,
       rownum = ROW_NUMBER()
                    OVER (
                        PARTITION BY iHTM.ModuleID
                        ORDER BY iHTM.Version DESC)
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[HtmlText] iHTM) htmVER
```

and when in the ON clause, be sure to include htmVER.rownum = 1 so that you get the first instance (i.e. greatest Version).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query if you only need the `Content` column (or another single one) from `HtmlText`. It also makes sure the Module or the Tab the module is on has not been deleted.

```
SELECT Modules.PortalID, TabModules.TabID, Tabs.TabName, Tabs.TabPath, Modules.ModuleID,
(SELECT TOP (1) [Content] FROM HtmlText WHERE (ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID) ORDER BY Version DESC) AS Content
FROM Modules
INNER JOIN TabModules ON TabModules.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID
INNER JOIN Tabs ON Tabs.TabID = TabModules.TabID
WHERE (Modules.ModuleDefID = 116) AND (Modules.IsDeleted = 0) AND (Tabs.IsDeleted = 0) AND (Modules.PortalID = 0)
ORDER BY Modules.PortalID, TabModules.TabID, Modules.ModuleID
```

You only need to check if the `ModuleDefID` is `116` or another number. This could vary per DNN install.

This can be found in the `ModuleDefinitions` table with the default `FriendlyName` being `Text/HTML`. You could include the `ModuleDefinitions` into the query and check the `FriendlyName` value, but that is possibly not a unique value (although unlikely)